# Node-orcaledb: execute() and executeMany() crash without error

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I am building an api rest with node-oracledb, I can retrieve all kind of data but the program breaks every time I try to do an insert.
This is the generic method I use to get a connection from the pool and perform the query.

```js
import oracledb from "oracledb";

export const executeQuery = async ({ query, binds, options, type, res }) => {
  let connection = null;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error al conectar OracleDB");
  }
  let result = null;
  try {
    result =
      type === "insertOne"
        ? await connection.execute(query, binds, options)
        : type === "insertMany"
        ? await connection.executeMany(query, binds, options)
        : null;
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("error", err.message);
    res.status(500).json("Error recuperando datos");
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        res.status(200).json(result.rows);
        // Always release the connection back to the pool
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

This is the controller method with which I am trying to insert a single record, in production the bind data would come from a post request.

```js
insertOneExample: async (req, res) => {
    const { items } = req.body;

    const query = `MERGE INTO SCHEMA.TABLE USING dual ON (CODIGO_HOSPI = :CODIGO_HOSPI AND CENTRO_ID = :CENTRO_ID) 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET PREV1 = :PREV1, PREV2 = :PREV2, PREV3 = :PREV3, PREV4 = :PREV4, PREV5 = :PREV5, PREV6 = :PREV6, PREV7 = :PREV7, PREV8 = :PREV8, PREV9 = :PREV9, PREV10 = :PREV10, PREV11 = :PREV11, PREV12 = :PREV12,
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (CODIGO_HOSPI, PREV1, PREV2, PREV3, PREV4, PREV5, PREV6, PREV7, PREV8, PREV9, PREV10, PREV11, PREV12, CENTRO_ID)
    VALUES (:CODIGO_HOSPI, :PREV1, :PREV2, :PREV3, :PREV4, :PREV5, :PREV6, :PREV7, :PREV8, :PREV9, :PREV10, :PREV11, :PREV12, :CENTRO_ID)`

    const options = {
      autoCommit: true,
      bindDefs: {
        CODIGO_HOSPI: { type: oracledb.STRING, maxSize: 20 },
        PREV1: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV2: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV3: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV4: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV5: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV6: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV7: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV8: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV9: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV10: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV11: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        PREV12: { type: oracledb.NUMBER },
        CENTRO_ID: { type: oracledb.STRING, maxSize: 10 },
      },
    };;
  
    executeQuery({
      query,
      binds: {
        CODIGO_HOSPI: "101",
        PREV1: 52600,
        PREV2: 870,
        PREV3: 123,
        PREV4: 564,
        PREV5: 846,
        PREV6: 625,
        PREV7: 897,
        PREV8: 124,
        PREV9: 656,
        PREV10: 456,
        PREV11: 324,
        PREV12: 212,
        CENTRO_ID: "10346",
      },
      options,
      type: "insertOne",
      res,
    });
  }
```

When executing the method, the server crashes without any error message.

[no error crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ng2Q.png)

*** sql statement is not the problem, it also crashes with a simple insert.

Comment: The only things I see from a quick scan are that you can reference `result.rows` when `result` is null, and also the case when there is no connection doesn't use `res`.  Try simplifying your code by removing columns & bind values (even all of them to check the basic flow works). You may think the statement isn't the problem but you need to verify it.  Don't chain the `.json` but put the return in a variable and check it is OK.  If you still need more help, update the question with a runnable script and include the CREATE TABLE. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try sending parameter values as strings instead of numbers, that fixed my issue.

Reference: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1377#issuecomment-1346171847